# Apps script deleted rule based on time

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I wrote an app script. It works correctly, but I have a problem. I got an error when sending an email to the specified address, from the message it seems that the error is related to a rule that does not exist (I have already deleted it together with the script that calls it). Please help.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you are seeing. Also, please add more details on your issue. Kindly check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)